# Using syslog to monitor stopped services on Win2k

Tags: windows-xp, event-log, windows-2000, syslogd, event-viewer

I am using a central syslog server to capture event logs from Windows machines.
I am specifically interested in monitoring Windows services. This works well under XP machines - each time a service starts or stops, I see it logged in syslog. The string captured is similar to "xxx service successfully sent a start control" or "stop control". However, on Windows 2000, each time I start/stop a service manually, nothing is logged in Event Viewer. Is this normal?